# How to add dpdk-dumpcap packet capture framework to a custom simple dpdk app

Tags: network-programming, packet-capture, dpdk

I am using dpdk_v22.11.1 on ubuntu_v22.04.2. I have a simple app derived from skeleton and icmpecho examples which can reply to proper arp requests and also can reply to appropriate pings. Now what are the proper steps to add a packet capture framework like dpdk-dumpcap here as the doc didn't clearly say it, but rather pointed out to check the testpmd.c

I simply added pdump header files, then initialized by rte_pdump_init(), then tried to run dpdk-dumpcap separately that was successful after running testpmd app but with my custom app it  failed to run Then I noticed configure_rxtx_dump_callbacks() in port initialization and tried to add it properly in my app but failed. I am just not sure whether I am on the right way or not. so please help if you have already passed this. thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to recompile dpdk-dumpcap and link dpdk's dynamic libraries to match your app

Comment: I did it anyway and worked with test-pmd. But I was unable to add support in my custom app, thats what I was really asking. what actual; steps should I follow to add certain things in my code so that later I can use dpdk-dumpcap with it. In the documentation it just said to follow "test-pmd" which isnt enough direction for me.